# Obter trecho de um String com expressão regular em JS

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Bem, o que eu necessito fazer é receber uma string via input, e "obter" certo valor dentro de tal tal string. Abaixo mostro um exemplo para ilustrar melhor a situação:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&amp;panoid=goEpsYZX7pQAAAQIt-TW4A&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed&amp;cbp=13%2C142.07416353827222%2C%2C0%2C-5.103108329005522"></iframe><div><small><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Views</a>: <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/view/110823397966309387614/gphoto/5911594599652857186" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Wien, Stephanplatz - at the Cathedral church Stephansdom.</a> de <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/110823397966309387614" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Bostjan Burger</a></small></div>
```

O objetivo aqui é resgatar o conteudo dentro do atributo `src=`. Para isso queria utilizar javascript, pois vou utilizar o evento onblur para que quando o usuario "cole" a string eu pegue o `src=` e passe para um `<iframe/>` exibir tal conteudo.

Partindo da premissa que consegui fazer isso utilizando um expressão regular `".*src=\"(.+?)\".*", "$1"` utilizando-se o metodo `replaceAll()` do Java como eu poderia realizar o mesmo em javascript?

Fiz algo, mas sem sucesso:

```
document.getElementById("yt_input").onblur = function{
    alert("Entrou no metodo...");
    var input = document.getElementById("yt_input").value;
    var expReg = ".*src=\"(.+?)\".*", "$1";
    var resultado = expReg.exec(input);

    alert("Valor do inputSplit:" + resultado[0]);

};
```

Qual seria a maneira correta de obter tal valor a fim de trabalhar com ele posteriormente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, está faltando um `()` depois de `function`, e aquela `, "$1"` na linha que criam a regex não são válidas em JavaScript. Com isso corrigimos os erros de sintaxe.

Segundo, você precisa de um objeto `RegExp` para usar expressões regulares, string só não basta. Você pode criá-lo a partir de um construtor ou de um literal:

```
//var expReg = ".*src=\"(.+?)\".*";
var expReg = new RegExp(".*src=\"(.+?)\".*");
var expReg = /.*src=\"(.+?)\".*/;
```

Por fim, para obter o primeiro grupo de captura você deve utilizar `resultado[1]`, não zero. O zero obtém o casamento completo (i.e. a string toda).

[Exemplo completo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg0t12bp/). P.S. Seria bom também testar `resultado` por `null` antes de usá-lo: pois é esse resultado que ocorrerá caso o valor do *input* não esteja no formato esperado.

Comment: Excelente resposta... +1!! :D